# How to include a Jison generated parser into angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jison

With the Jison library one can generate parsers given a specific grammar like:

> $ jison calculator.jison

As stated in [1] .

That would generate a parser `calculator.js`.

But how to include the generated parser `calculator.js` in an angular project?

[1] - https://gerhobbelt.github.io/jison/docs/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Use the 'import' statement, in app.module.ts or some other module. The longer answer is: Consider wrapping it up in an npm package, uploading it to npmjs, and importing it like any other npm package...